# $\left(\bigcap_{i∈I} A_i\right) \times B = \bigcap_{i ∈ I} \left(A_i \times B\right)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Suppose $I \neq \emptyset$. Prove that for any indexed family of sets $\{A_i\,|\,i \in I\}$ and any set B
$$\left(\bigcap_{i∈I} A_i\right) \times B = \bigcap_{i ∈ I} \left(A_i \times B\right).$$
Where **exactly** in the proof does the assumption that $I \neq \emptyset$ get used?

Comment: I think the statement is only true for $I\not=\emptyset$

Comment: I think there is a nuance in what the 'empty product' $A_i \times B$ should be, if there is no $A_i$ appearing. Categorically speaking, the empty product should be a singleton (as it is the final object in the category of sets), i.e. a set with one element, let us say $\{\ast\}$. On the other hand, the empty intersection should be $\emptyset$. But if you did not encounter category theory yet, let us say, everyhing boils down to **how the text you are reading defined empty products and empty intersections**. Maybe they did not define them at all and thus assumed that $I \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

*One interpretation*
For a family $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ of subsets of a set $E$, we define
$$
\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i = \big\{u \in E \,:\, \forall i\in I, u \in A_i\big\}
$$
So if $I = \varnothing$, we get
$$
\bigcap_{i \in \varnothing} A_i = \big\{u \in E \,:\, \forall i\in \varnothing, u \in A_i\big\} = E .
$$
Note that the answer is $E$, the set where all $A_i$ are chosen as subsets.

Now, suppose $(A_i)_{ii \in I}$ is a family of subsets of $E$ and $B \subseteq F$, where **we must know $E,F$ from the context**.  Then $(A_i \times B)_{i\in I}$ is a family of subsets of $E \times F$.
$$
\left(\bigcap_{i \in \varnothing} A_i\right) \times B = E \times B
\\
\bigcap_{i \in \varnothing} (A_i \times B) = E \times F
$$

---

So for example, we can easily make an example where $E = F = \mathbb R$.

Think of this.  Is it even possible to specify a family of sets $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ without first specifying a set $E$ where all the $A_i$ lie?  Write the definition of $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ technically, using axioms of ZF (perhaps the axiom of separation?)